# Arrow Analysis throws "NosuchMethod" exception

Tags: arrow-kt

I'm trying to use arrow analysis in my project to catch exceptions at compile time. I follow this [page](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/meta/analysis/#running-the-analysis) but when I do Gradle build I get a bunch of runtime exceptions

It's my test code

```
fun main() {
    val wrong = emptyList<Int>().get(2)
}
```

It's my Gradle DSL build script

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.10"
}
group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    implementation("io.arrow-kt:arrow-core:1.1.2")
}
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("io.arrow-kt.analysis.kotlin:io.arrow-kt.analysis.kotlin.gradle.plugin:2.0")
    }
}
apply(plugin = "io.arrow-kt.analysis.kotlin")
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting when doing the Gradle build

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtExpression org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.callUtil.CallUtilKt.getReceiverExpression(org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.model.ResolvedCall)'
    at arrow.meta.plugins.analysis.phases.analysis.solver.ast.kotlin.KotlinResolvedCall.getReceiverExpression(KotlinResolvedCall.kt:37)
    at arrow.meta.plugins.analysis.phases.analysis.solver.ResolvedCallUtilsKt.allArgumentExpressions(ResolvedCallUtils.kt:75)
    at arrow.meta.plugins.analysis.phases.analysis.solver.ResolvedCallUtilsKt.arg(ResolvedCallUtils.kt:119)
    at arrow.meta.plugins.analysis.phases.analysis.solver.check.ExpressionsKt.controlFlowAnyFunction(Expressions.kt:438)
    at arrow.meta.plugins.analysis.phases.analysis.solver.check.ExpressionsKt.checkCallExpression(Expressions.kt:397)
    at arrow.meta.plugins.analysis.phases.analysis.solver.check.ExpressionsKt.fallThrough(Expressions.kt:260)
    at arrow.meta.plugins.analysis.phases.analysis.solver.check.ExpressionsKt.access$fallThrough(Expressions.kt:1)
    at arrow.meta.plugins.analysis.phases.analysis.solver.check.ExpressionsKt$checkExpressionConstraints$2.invoke(Expressions.kt:244)
    at arrow.meta.plugins.analysis.phases.analysis.solver.check.ExpressionsKt$checkExpressionConstraints$2.invoke(Expressions.kt:157)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeq$flatMap$1.invokeSuspend(ContSeq.kt:60)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.hasNext(ContSeq.kt:233)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeq$map$1.invokeSuspend(ContSeq.kt:292)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.hasNext(ContSeq.kt:233)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeq$map$1.invokeSuspend(ContSeq.kt:292)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.hasNext(ContSeq.kt:233)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeq$map$1.invokeSuspend(ContSeq.kt:292)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.hasNext(ContSeq.kt:233)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.yieldAll(ContSeq.kt:274)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqSyntax$DefaultImpls.yieldAll(ContSeq.kt:165)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.yieldAll(ContSeq.kt:203)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeq$flatMap$1.invokeSuspend(ContSeq.kt:60)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.hasNext(ContSeq.kt:233)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeq$map$1.invokeSuspend(ContSeq.kt:292)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.hasNext(ContSeq.kt:233)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeq$map$1.invokeSuspend(ContSeq.kt:292)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.hasNext(ContSeq.kt:233)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.yieldAll(ContSeq.kt:274)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqSyntax$DefaultImpls.yieldAll(ContSeq.kt:165)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.yieldAll(ContSeq.kt:203)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeq$flatMap$1.invokeSuspend(ContSeq.kt:60)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.hasNext(ContSeq.kt:233)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeq$map$1.invokeSuspend(ContSeq.kt:292)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.hasNext(ContSeq.kt:233)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeq$map$1.invokeSuspend(ContSeq.kt:292)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.hasNext(ContSeq.kt:233)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.yieldAll(ContSeq.kt:274)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqSyntax$DefaultImpls.yieldAll(ContSeq.kt:165)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.yieldAll(ContSeq.kt:203)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeq$flatMap$1.invokeSuspend(ContSeq.kt:60)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.hasNext(ContSeq.kt:233)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeq$map$1.invokeSuspend(ContSeq.kt:292)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.hasNext(ContSeq.kt:233)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeq$map$1.invokeSuspend(ContSeq.kt:292)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.hasNext(ContSeq.kt:233)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.yieldAll(ContSeq.kt:274)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqSyntax$DefaultImpls.yieldAll(ContSeq.kt:165)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.yieldAll(ContSeq.kt:203)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeq$flatMap$1.invokeSuspend(ContSeq.kt:60)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.hasNext(ContSeq.kt:233)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.yieldAll(ContSeq.kt:274)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqSyntax$DefaultImpls.yieldAll(ContSeq.kt:165)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.yieldAll(ContSeq.kt:203)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeq$flatMap$1.invokeSuspend(ContSeq.kt:60)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeqBuilder.hasNext(ContSeq.kt:233)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeq.drain(ContSeq.kt:297)
    at arrow.meta.plugins.analysis.phases.analysis.solver.check.EntryPointKt.checkDeclarationConstraints(EntryPoint.kt:69)
    at arrow.meta.plugins.analysis.phases.PhasesKt$analysisPhases$4.invoke(Phases.kt:128)
    at arrow.meta.plugins.analysis.phases.PhasesKt$analysisPhases$4.invoke(Phases.kt:121)
    at arrow.meta.dsl.config.ConfigSyntax$storageComponent$1.check(ConfigSyntax.kt:72)
    at arrow.meta.internal.registry.InternalRegistry$DelegatingContributor$registerModuleComponents$2.check(InternalRegistry.kt:651)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.ModifiersChecker$ModifiersCheckingProcedure.runDeclarationCheckers(ModifiersChecker.java:285)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.ModifiersChecker$ModifiersCheckingProcedure.checkModifierListCommon(ModifiersChecker.java:224)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.ModifiersChecker$ModifiersCheckingProcedure.checkModifiersForDeclaration(ModifiersChecker.java:183)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.DeclarationsChecker.process(DeclarationsChecker.kt:102)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.BodyResolver.resolveBodies(BodyResolver.java:258)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer.analyzeDeclarations(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:227)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer.analyzeDeclarations$default(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:58)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:130)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:264)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:255)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.repeatAnalysisIfNeeded(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:189)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.repeatAnalysisIfNeeded(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:189)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:60)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:157)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:477)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:127)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:366)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally$default(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:311)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:175)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:75)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:625)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1739)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

***Is there any specific JVM version or kotlin version required to use this in the project?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you check with version 2.0.2? This bug (or at least a very similar one) was fixed in that version.

Comment: no luck! same problem in 2.0.2 also

Comment: And with `2.0.3-alpha.2`?

Comment: Yepp, It works!